# Does present perfect fit after since in this case?

Tags: since

I am writing to a record label that has not released a record for a long time, and here is the first sentence that I have  written

It has been a very long time since you **have released** a new record

My question:

Does present perfect fit in this case?

I know I could write :

"It has been a very long time since you last **released** a record"  implying a specific record (the last one)

or

Your label **has not released** any record for a long time.

but I ve chosen present perfect"It has been a long time since you **have released** a new record "  because it seems better for me  for 3 reasons :

First  :  I am not talking about a precise record but the act of releasing a record in general.

Second  : They have released many records before.

Third   : At the time of writing they still have not released  any new record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Introduction

> I am not talking about a precise record but the act of releasing a record in general.

Actually you're talking about a point of time when the **last** record was released. Otherwise, your sentence won't make much sense - why would you say *"It's been a long time since you released a new record"* if you didn't imply the most recent one?

> They have released many records before.

So what? You still refer to a point of time when the **last** record was released.

> At the time of writing they still have not released any new record.

A period of time when records were released ended, but a non-release period hasn't ended yet. So, the latter can be used in *Present Perfect* while the other one can't.

#### Conclusion

Hence, your sentence can be as follows:

> It has been a very long time since you released a new record.

However, your alternative sounds even better:

> It has been a very long time since you last released a record.